# Does the Spark DAG visualization ever have outgoingEdges?

Tags: apache-spark, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm looking into the Spark UI DAG visualization code and found the following [snippet](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/2338451266d37b4c952827325cdee53b3e8fbc78/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ui/scope/RDDOperationGraph.scala#L187):

```
edges.foreach { case e: RDDOperationEdge =>
  val fromThisGraph = nodes.contains(e.fromId)
  val toThisGraph = nodes.contains(e.toId)
  (fromThisGraph, toThisGraph) match {
    case (true, true) => internalEdges += e
    case (true, false) => outgoingEdges += e
    case (false, true) => incomingEdges += e
    // should never happen
    case _ => logWarning(s"Found an orphan edge in stage ${stage.stageId}: $e")
```

To my understanding, internal edges represent edges between RDDs within a stage, incoming edges come from an earlier stage to an RDD in the current stage, and outgoing edges would come from an RDD in the current stage to a subsequent stage. However, since [edges are created based on the RDDs parentIds](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/2338451266d37b4c952827325cdee53b3e8fbc78/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ui/scope/RDDOperationGraph.scala#L139), I have a hard time understanding how outgoing edges could ever be present, as the RDD with the parentId pointing to the current stage would not be found in the analysis of the current stage.

Am I correct in my assumption that outgoingEdges would never be present?

Answer (score 0):

outgoingEdges could be present and they are edges with no node present at the end.

If you observe the line

```
case (true, false) => outgoingEdges += e
```

fromThisGraph = true i.e., e.fromId is present in nodes;
toThisGraph = false i.e., e.toId is not present in nodes which mean the other end of the branch is connected to no node

```
---------------      e
|     node    |------>-----        
---------------
```

Similarly for incomingEdges, there is no starting node.

---

I hope that I'm making sense

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. I understand what the edges are, but the question is will they ever be created, as [this](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/2338451266d37b4c952827325cdee53b3e8fbc78/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ui/scope/RDDOperationGraph.scala#L139) appears to be the only place they are created. The right hand side of the edge is created from the `rddInfo`s of the current stage in that snippet, and I can't see another place where the right hand side could be assigned to something *not* from the current stage's `rddInfo`s.

Comment: I think YES. [val isAllowed](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/2338451266d37b4c952827325cdee53b3e8fbc78/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ui/scope/RDDOperationGraph.scala#L129) is true even for outgoingEdges or incomingEdges. In that case, the edge is created. Correct me if I'm missing something here.